# Bootstrap 3 doesn't include respond.js because it doesn't deem IE8 important - right?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3, respond.js

It seems that the Bootstrap developers dropped support for IE8 but I still notice that some people include respond.js for CSS media query support in IE8.

Would you only include this 'if' your audience are old school and might use IE8?

So, if your traffic is a bit more tech savvy then would you bother including respond.js?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your site is tech-savy, has pretty modern effects and design, you're going to face a hell of a headache working around to support IE8. I know that because I had the same problem for multiple sites I worked on. Things would work fine on all browsers (chrome, FF and so on) but IE? uh huh. Do some hoops first.

However, that kinda changed when I learned about [chrome frame](http://www.google.com/chromeframe). It's a plugin for IE that runs a chrome within it. Just tell any user using IE8 (or older, really) to install it, then all you have to do is add a little meta tag at the top of the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
```

And that's it! you've got IE8 support covered. For me , learning about it was a lifesaver, and ever since has always been the easiest and sanest solution out there (not to mention the site looks great even inside the IE tab). Good luck!

p.s.
Google is planning to stop supporting it because, well, less and less people are using IE8, but the plugin is fine as it is.

Comment: Thanks - very helpful info. I guess that with 4.1% IE8 usage according to W3 it maybe just isnt worth it...

Comment: Yeah exactly. That's why the plugin is perfect - minimal effort and complete support

Answer (score 0):

Ahh... it works in IE8 I just discovered that no need to add any meta tags just add respond.js (easily available) before head please don't add it in conditional comment it will not work

after adding this you need a testing server as it will not work on your local machine...

Thanks and regards,
Kiran Tawde